# ADF Use Variable in Task Flow payload in View Object bound variable

Tags: oracle-adf, bpmn, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a simple Task Flow that has a bunch of Master/Child data controls bound by Data Components.

The task flow was created using a Human Task file and as such has a payload that it accepts ( `getTaskDetails -> Return -> Task -> Payload` ) that is viewable in my Data Controls panel:

[image: Task Flow Payload viewable in Data Controls]

I have an App Module that has a bunch of ADF Business Components that are connected to my backend database:

[image: Business Components in Panel]

My parent component (SdfValidationErrorEvents) I would like to select based on a primary key value that I pass into the task flow as part of the payload (eventID).  So I created a bound variable that I could use in my SQL View Criteria, and I created a view criteria where I select based on eventID:

[image: Bound Variable and View Criteria]

My question is how do I set the bound variable's value to the Task Flow payload's value?  What's the expression for fetching the Task Flow's payload entity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by payload you mean input parameter. You can define taskflow`s input and output parameters in taskflow`s "Overview" tab, section "Parameters". Define input parameter e.g. myPayload and you will see that you can access it in pageFlowScope with expression:
`#{pageFlowScope.myPayload}`

Comment: I created this taskflow from a BPMN human task file.  The task file defined a payload to pass to the taskflow.  When I look at the task flow's input parameters, I don't see the BPMN-created payload that I had defined, only auto generated input parameters.

Comment: Could it be that one of auto generated input parameters is your payload?

Comment: Could be - I've yet to figure out which one it is, if any of them :)  This link shows somewhat what I'm trying to do (I think) but through Java code.  I need to access the payload through the GUI [link](http://adfexpress.blogspot.com/2012/01/to-retrieve-oracle-bpm-worklist-payload.html)

Comment: Essentially the task flow payload is accessed through the Task's `getTaskDetails` which returns a Task Object which contains that payload... I think I need a way to access that through EL.

Comment: OK - So I was able to bind the necessary payload variables into the adf page, so now it shows up as a binding in the bindings tab.  How do I access a binding through expression in the View Object's bind variables?

Comment: You bind view object`s variable through data control. This is not the place for tutorial, but here is one: http://ecmtechnicalexpertise.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/adf-11g-passing-information-to-bind-variables/